# How to write file checking code for best performance

Tags: php, file

Is there any appreciable difference, in terms of speed on a low-traffic website, between the following snippets of code?

```
$html = file_get_contents('cache/foo.html');

if ($html) {
    echo $html;
    exit;
}
```

Or this:

```
$file = 'cache/foo.html';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo file_get_contents($file);
    exit;
}
```

In the first snippet, there's a single call to file_get_contents() whereas in the second there's also a call to file_exists(). The page does involve database access - and this caching would avoid that entirely.

Comment: The one with file_exists will be SLIGHTLY slower, but should not be significant . (REASON: it does one more step : to validate that the file does exist)

Comment: great question! , i've been questioning my self this for the last 2 weeks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be unnoticeably slower on a low-traffic website; but there is no reason to perform that check anyway if you're going to get the contents if it exists, since `file_get_contents()` already performs that check behind-the-scenes, returning `false` if the file doesn't exist.

You can even put the call to `file_get_contents()` directly inside the condition:

```php
if ($html = file_get_contents('cache/foo.html')) {
    echo $html;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Beware of any file contents that result in a falsy value, like the empty string or string "0". You can do an inline if with explicitely checking for false by using for example `if (false !== ($html = file_get_contents('cache/foo.html'))`

Answer (score 1):

The runtime differences are so minimal for both variants that it does not matter in practice.
The first variant is slightly faster if the file exists. The second variant is faster if the file does not exist.
Both solutions do not have the best performance because the entire HTML is first loaded into memory before the output is done with echo. Better is:

```
$ok = @readfile ('cache/foo.html');
```

With readfile the file is output directly or without detours. The @ operator suppresses the warning if the file does not exist.
$ok contains the number of bytes output if the output was successful and false if the file does not exist.

Comment: This is really good